# sql update procedure

Tags: sql

I have used an SQL function to update single records when called:  The function is:
function ToggleAnimalExclusion (AnimalId in number, StudyID in number) return number is

```
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
exVal varchar2 (1);

begin
    select exclude 
    into exVal
    from mbddx_study
    where study_name = AnimalId and study_id = StudyID;

if (exVal is null) then
    update mbddx_study
    set exclude = 'Y'
    where study_name = AnimalId and study_id = StudyID ;
else
    update mbddx_study
    set exclude = NULL
    where study_name = AnimalId and study_id = StudyID ;
end if ;

commit;
return 0;
end ;
```

This works when called from a Perl script and the single database field is updated.

Now, I want to update a grouping of fields, using the same structure as above, but each study_name is part of a study_group.  SO I want to update the whole group, when the group number is passed in (instead of the study_name).

The code I have is:

```
function ToggleBoxExclusion (BoxId in number, StudyID in number) return number is
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    exVal varchar2 (1);
begin
    select exclude 
    into exVal
    from mbddx_animal
    where box = BoxId and study_id = StudyID;

    if (exVal is null) then
        update mbddx_animal
        set exclude = 'Y'
        where box = BoxId and study_id = StudyID ;
    else
        update mbddx_animal
        set exclude = NULL
        where box = BoxId and study_id = StudyID ;
    end if ;

    commit;
    return 0;
end ;
```

As you can see, it is very similar and I think the problem lies with me trying to update a number of fields.  As it stands, no fields are updated when I call this function.

Any ideas?#

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first suggestion is to run it as a select with your where clause and make sure any records are being returned. (Have you checked the values for box and study_id in the function?)
Also, if you write the code as:

```
if (exVal is null) then tempExclude := 'Y' else tempExclude := NULL;
Update mbddx_animal
set exclude = tempExclude where...
```

it will be easier to maintain (one update statement instead of 2)

Comment: Hi,  Yes, when I run it as a select statement, they are being returned fine.

Comment: then next step is tyo try the update statement outside the fucntion. If it works with the box/study you ecxpect to appear in the function, next thign I would do is print their values before the update statement.
Also, assuming this is PLSQL and it returns 0 it should be a Procedure

Comment: Would it matter that the statement is not in a loop of some kind?

Comment: how are you invoking the function? Have you printed out the params from within the function to see what they are set to? Why is this being done as an autonomous transaction? Why do you allow the compiler to do implicit data type conversion for you? return should be '0' since return type is a varchar2. And, since you are returning only a single character, return type should be Char. But, as I said before this should be coded as a procedure, not a function.

Comment: Hi, I have got around this now, by changing the logic slightly.  Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: could I see the change you made?